# How simplify the pentagonal equation from two fusion rings?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, subfactors, fusion-categories

A semi-simple finite dimensional Hopf algebra $\mathbb{A}$, and its dual $\mathbb{A}^{*}$ produce two fusion categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}^{*}$ and then two fusion rings $\mathcal{R}_{1}$ and $\mathcal{R}_{2}$.

A fusion category $\mathcal{C}$ is in fact given by one solution of the pentagonal equation on its fusion ring $\mathcal{R}$.

Starting with a fusion ring $\mathcal{R}$, it's in general quite difficult (or unattainable) of solving the pentagonal equation.

But if we start with two fusion rings $\mathcal{R}_{1}$ and $\mathcal{R}_{2}$ (so more constraints) :

> Is there a simplified manner to find some related fusion categories in
>   duality $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}^{*}$, and then semi-simple
>   finite dimensional Hopf algebras in duality $\mathbb{A}$ and 
>   $\mathbb{A}^{*}$ ?

Comment: How do you produce the fusion category from the Hopf algebra? Do you mean the representation category?

Comment: @Turion: yes. Here we deal with the representation category and the corepresentation category.

Comment: But the representation category can always be endowed with the trivial associator from vector spaces, right? I guess I don't completely understand your question.

Comment: I think fusion categories always representations of some quasi-Hopf algebras. But those are not coassociative, they only are if the associator is trivial.

Comment: @Turion: I'm not an expert but I don't think so (at least in the sense I know, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176400/are-there-workable-algebraic-geometry-approaches-for-the-pentagon-equation?rq=1)). Note that there are fusion rings which are not categorifiable.

Comment: @Turion: And yes, any fusion category is equivalent to
the category of finite dimensional representations of a (nonunique)
regular connected semisimple weak Hopf algebra (see Corollary 2.22 [here](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v162-n2-p01.pdf))

Comment: I'm just saying that if you take the category of representations of an honest Hopf algebra, then you can choose the associators to be trivial. That's got nothing to do with the fusion ring of your category. If you want the associators to be nontrivial, you'll probably have to make the comultiplication not coassociative. So I don't see how you would always find a semi-simple finite dimensional Hopf algebra. (Or I didn't understand your question.)

Comment: @Turion: the representation category of a finite dimensional Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra is associative. This does not imply that the associators of the related fusion category can be chosen trivial. Perhaps there is a misunderstanding on what the associators are (see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2P_JgZe-Zd0OVRjakNSUUhleUk/view) p29-30). If you disagree, do you have a reference?

Comment: If you have the representations of a Hopf algebra, you have a _monoidal_ fibre functor to vector spaces (as in Ostrik's paper you cite), where vector spaces is equipped with the canonical associator $u \otimes (v \otimes w) \mapsto (u \otimes v) \otimes w$. That's what I mean by a trivial associator. (Of course, the F-matrices can still look weird if you choose a poor basis for the fusion spaces, but that's just gauge freedom.)

Comment: In order to get truly nontrivial associators, you need a weak Hopf algebra (or a Quasi-Hopf algebra) that is _not_ a Hopf algebra, i.e. either the comultiplication must be twisted coassociative, or the compatibility between algebra and coalgebra structures must be weakened.