# Are there workable numerical approaches for the pentagon equation?

Tags: finite-groups, na.numerical-analysis, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, fusion-categories

> **Warning**: this post is the "numerical" analog of
>     [Are there workable algebraic geometry approaches for the pentagon equation?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/176400/34538)
>   I've replaced "algebraic geometry" by "numerical" in its content,
>   otherwise it's almost the same.

This question is *mainly* intended for experts in numerical analysis.
A competence in the pentagon equation is *not* necessary.

A pentagon equation is a system of polynomial equations of degree $3$ with several variables and integer coefficients, given by a fusion ring.

A fusion ring is given by a finite set of integer matrices checking some axioms (see [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2P_JgZe-Zd0OVRjakNSUUhleUk) p 22).
A solution of its pentagon equation is the main condition for having a structure of fusion category,
in which it encodes associativity (see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203060.pdf)). For example, the  irreducible complex representations
of a finite group, equipped with $\oplus$ and $\otimes$, generate a fusion ring and a fusion category.

The problem is that, in practice the pentagon equations we meet are huge, for example, a system of $2000000$ polynomial equations with  $50000$ variables (of degree $3$ with integer coefficients), so that proving the existence of a solution (and *a fortiori* finding one) is very hard.
Note that there are pentagon equations without solution.

**Question**:  Are there workable numerical approaches ?
(for highlighting or proving the existence of a solution, or for finding a numerical one)

In fact, the pentagon equation is more structured than just a system of scalar equations, it's a system of several invertible (unitary) matrix equations of the form $$A_1 A_2 A_3  = A_4 A_5$$
(and $A_i^* A_i  = I$), such that $A_i = \tau_i B_i \tau'_i$, with $\tau_i$,$\tau'_i$ fixed permutation matrices and $B_i$ a block diagonal matrix (each block is a matrix variable), so that there are many holes (see [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2P_JgZe-Zd0OVRjakNSUUhleUk) p 29-30).
Note that in general $\nu_1\nu_2\nu_3 \neq \nu_4\nu_5$  (with $\nu_i = \tau_i\tau'_i$), so that $B_i =I$ can't be a solution.

I'm interested in the equation given by [this fusion ring](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132866/non-weakly-group-theoretical-integral-fusion-categories). There are $16227$ matrix equations of dimensions from $1$ to $91$, and $2097$ invertible (unitary) matrix variables of dimensions from $1$ to $17$ (see [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2P_JgZe-Zd0OVRjakNSUUhleUk) p 31).

Comment: Why don't you just edit the previous question by changing "algebraic geometry" to "algebraic geometry or numerical analysis"?

Comment: @StefanKohl: Don't you read the warning? Moreover I've answered to the comment of Scott.

Comment: The question is obviously not a duplicate. That it might have been better to create a common generalisation of the two questions is orthogonal to this. (Personally, I am not even sure this would have been better.)

Comment: @quid: Much of the text of the two questions is the same, except for the attached warning and the precise question asked. Anyway -- I see your point not to attribute this question as a "duplicate" of the other question.

Comment: @StefanKohl yes the situation is a bit unusual. I am not sure what I would do if we get still more questions of this form, iterating through various subjects. Likely, I would report OP at some point for littering the site. But one other one after more than a week is decidedly below my threshold for doing this.

Comment: See the post: [What are the numerical methods for huge polynomial systems?](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/14291/9824)