# 6j symbols of SU(4) at level 4

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, fusion-categories

Does anybody know of a reference that gives the (quantum) 6j symbols of SU(4) at level 4?

Alternatively, I know the S-matrix and the fusion rules, in the form
$a \times b = \sum_i N^{ab}_{c_i} c_i$
Is there a simple way to compute all quantum 6j symbols from these?

Comment: This question is a little unclear as it stands. can you include definitions of $N$ and $a,b,c$? This will help uses from pure math decipher applied questions better.

Comment: The $N_{ab}^c$ are the dimensions of the $hom(a \otimes b,c )$ spaces in the fusion categories for $SU(4)_4$.

Comment: I can't think of a reference for your first question and I don't think there is one. All of the sources I can think of are for $SU(2)_k$. The standard knowledge about solving pentagon equations however is basically contained in [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/176400/are-there-workable-algebraic-geometry-approaches-for-the-pentagon-equation/177162#177162).

Comment: I think there are some physics papers that calculate part of the 6j symbols for $SU(N)$. But, to me it is actually not even clear if there is a unique categorification of the $SU(N)_k$ fusion rules for $N>2$.

Comment: There isn't. The details for why this is true are in Kazhdan-Wenzl's "Reconstructing Monoidal Categories."

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your second question, no, there is not a simple way to compute $6j$-symbols from the fusion rules and the $S$-matrix.

Comment: Curious if it's not known or there's reason behind.